# Basic and simple linq to sql, not sure what's wrong

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I a have a simple linq to sql query and for some reason the .take() doesn't work. I tried to add skip() as well thinking that maybe it needed some starting point from where to take the records but the results are still same and rather than taking only 10 records, it takes all 240 records.

Would appreciate if somebody can tell me what's going on. Thanks in advance.

The code is:

```
var types = (from t in EventTypes.tl_event_types
                        select new
                        {
                            type_id = t.event_type_id,
                            type_name = t.type_name
                        }).Take(10);
```

Comment: Looking at the code, what you're describing doesn't make sense. Can you post the code that follows this snippet?

Comment: Put it in debug mode and mouse over the query, it should tell you the SQL it is executing, and should indicate the problem.

Comment: I copy & pasted your code into LinqPad and changed the entities to ones I had, and it returned 10 records, not the 5k that are in my table

Comment: How do you say it returns 240 records, piece of code shown above is not actually executing the query. Can you try to convert your query to list types.ToList() and then find out the number records

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by naming conventions that EventTypes is your object.  You need to select from your data context...  So

```
var types = (from t in dataContext.EventTypes.tl_event_types
                    select new
                    {
                        type_id = t.event_type_id,
                        type_name = t.type_name
                    }).Take(10);
```

should work.